# how do I get Reddit API Authorisation token with only using http request

Tags: json, api, reddit, make.com, reddit-access-token

how do I get **Reddit API Authorisation token** with only using **http request**.

I'm very new to API and don't have very much experience. and I am finding Reddit API to be little bit confusing coz unlike other API in reddit first we need to get authorisation token through client ID and secret.

I couldn't figure out how to get the authorisation token I am unsure to which parameters to use and what not there are few videos about it on YouTube but all of them are for python and their using some other library which I couldn't understand since I am new to programming.

I want to to get the authorisation token using integromat's http module I tried few ways to get the authorisation token but failed every time I am unsure to which module to use between these https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBmUm.png I tried few of them but wasn't able to get it going with any. and I am also unsure to if I need to put the parameters in header or in body or somewhere else https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywo4W.png and I have put the redirect URL in the the Reddit client app as [https://www.integromat.com/oauth/cb/[my-integromat-app-id]](https://www.integromat.com/oauth/cb/%5Bmy-integromat-app-id%5D) but things are still not working I am pretty sure it's a error on my end https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCchw.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/mThme.png this is the current parameters and values I am using do I need to add anything more am I doing this wrong can someone please correct me